# Determine if Intel I processor or RAM has hardware failure?

Tags: hardware, intel

I have the suspicion that either my Intel I2500K has a hardware problem or the RAM has a hardware problem.

How can i determine if there is hardware failure or exclude that?

EDIT: The processor has a hardware failure indeed. I figured that through deactivating cores in the bios. It turned out that core 3 has failure, everything works fine if only two cores are activated. The Kernel panic message did point to that as core 3 was mentioned there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For RAM, try [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). Many distros used to come with it on their live CDs but I'm not sure if that is still the case.

Comment: synaptic sais its installed but getting "sudo: memtest86+: command not found"

Comment: It's not a command, it's something you have to boot into. If synaptic says it's installed it's probably in your GRUB menu. Reboot your computer and hold shift when it starts booting, you should get into the GRUB menu and have memtest86+ as an option. Note that it's a very thorough test, it can take quite some time (hours) to run a full pass through all your RAM.

Comment: The Ram test takes a very long time on 4+4gig ddr3 rams, after almost two hours it had two passes zero errorst at 50% progress. Im still looking for a way to determine if the CPU has a hardware failure.

Comment: @Aurigae CPU failures are extremely rare. RAM failures are fairly common. RAM tests *do* take a long time and don't always detect problems that can appear in practice because RAM failures are very sensitive to access patterns; memtest86+ tries various access patterns but it doesn't always stress the RAM as much as real use.